# How to validate chosen data in laravel request file?

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel Request to validate data but those data are json so I got data and convert them to array
what i need to do now is validating $details from the code below.
is there any way to validate them inside the request file apart from using request->validate in controller?

my request file:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
class PublicRegisterRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        $details = json_decode($this->request->get('details'));
        return [
            'firstName' => 'required|max:25',
            'lastName' => 'required|max:25',
            'fatherName' => 'required|max:25',

        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: why is `details` a string not an (json) object already? Have you access to the frontend to modifiy it?

Comment: from front-end it was json so in back-end I convert it to std class in order to validate items inside the json I don't want to validate the json file but data inside json

Comment: did you try `'details.firstName' => '....'`?

Comment: You can prepare data for validation and then override the existing data with the prepared data, for more info. see: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#preparing-input-for-validation

Comment: @Sysix I didn't but it works thank you so much

Comment: @MahmoudMohamedRamadan Thank you I read more about preparing input for validation it is realy useful function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you access to client side, its proper to get details body instead .
I mean instead of getting :

```
{
  "details" :{
            'firstName' : '...',
            'lastName' : '...',
            'fatherName' : '...',
   }
}
```

You should get :

```
{
  'firstName' : '...',
  'lastName' : '...',
  'fatherName' : '...',
}
```

But , if you dont access to client side , simply you can use this pattern in your request class :

```
 public function rules()
    {

        return [
            'details.firstName' => 'required|max:25',
            'details.lastName' => 'required|max:25',
            'details.fatherName' => 'required|max:25',

        ];
    }
```

Hope that would works.

Comment: Thank you saeed I tried that and it worked properly ... I really appreciate your help